# Why my Jupyter toolbar lacking TOC and Reference button

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

According [to this link](http://jupyter.cs.brynmawr.edu/hub/dblank/public/Jupyter%20Notebook%20Users%20Manual.ipynb#1.-Getting-to-Know-your-Jupyter-Notebook's-Toolbar) we can get TOC/Reference toolbar in [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/):

[image]

But why mine those 3 buttons don't appear?
How can I enable them?

I tried installing calico.
Using this

```
$ sudo ipython install-nbextension https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/downloads/calico-document-tools-1.0.zip
Password:
downloading https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/downloads/calico-document-tools-1.0.zip to /tmp/tmpAG0vDt/calico-document-tools-1.0.zip
extracting /tmp/tmpAG0vDt/calico-document-tools-1.0.zip to /usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions
```

Then do this which give me failure.

```
In [1]: import IPython

In [2]: IPython.load_extensions('calico-document-tools');
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0e54e8411271> in <module>()
----> 1 IPython.load_extensions('calico-document-tools');

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_extensions'

  [1]: http://jupyter.cs.brynmawr.edu/hub/dblank/public/Jupyter%20Notebook%20Users%20Manual.ipynb#1.-Getting-to-Know-your-Jupyter-Notebook's-Toolbar
  [2]: https://jupyter.org/
```

Comment: There are no links. 

You can find how to install a nbextension to install ToC functionality from [here](https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions#table-of-contents).

Answer (score 3):

The functionality you are talking about don't come by default with Jupyter notebook.

There are some repos where you can find extensions that can be 'easily' installed to improve the basic functionality of the notebook. Here you can find some extensions ready to be installed:

- https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions
- https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions
- Others on github